# Change maximal server response time

Tags: php, time, webserver, response

When i try to use my php script, i allways get 504 Gateway Time-out. 
I am sure, that the server will respons a bit later.
Is it possible to change the time until the error appears ?
Edit: my hoster limits the respons time :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function set_time_limit($seconds); So you can control the maximum executing time

Comment: i set it to 2 hours, but i get 504 after 30 seconds.

Comment: It must be because your hosting provider don't allow to modify the time limit so you don't user their server too much.

Maybe you can improve your code/algorithm so it will take less than 30 seconds

Comment: i want to sent a lot of mails, i can not improve the time of that ^^

Comment: Assuming you have an array of 100000 mails addresses. you can do something like that : http://pastebin.com/XCZnWNCt
(Sorry I forgot to stop the loop when there is no more mails to send :/ )

Comment: im getting 504 with this, too.